# Gradle warnings of deprecated property

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-studio, jacoco

I don't understand, why gradle doesn't build? I use Android Studio, Gradle 1.12.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories {
    maven { url '***' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testPackageName "***"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
            runProguard false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    jacoco {
        version = '0.6.2.201302030002'
    }

    testOptions {
        resultsDir = "$project.buildDir/jacoco"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.activeandroid:activeandroid:3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest'
    }
    compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
    testCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.1'
}
```

When I sync gradle with project it throw warnings:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources]
>   Warning:Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>   Warning:Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main
>   artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle
>   2.0 Warning:The Test.testReportDir property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the
>   Test.getReports().getHtml().getDestination() property instead.
>   :app:preBuild :app:preDebugBuild :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild :app:preStageBuild
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4452Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE Information:BUILD
>   SUCCESSFUL Information:Total time: 6.457 secs Information:0 errors
>   Information:3 warnings

Comment: It says BUILD SUCCESSFUL and you are saying the build was not successful. I am so confused!

Comment: Doesn't matter, because application all the same not running.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the plugin "gradle-android-test-plugin". JakeWharton announced this plugin as deprecated. Maby probably because this is not going to project. I removed plugin and change build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories {
    maven { url '***' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testPackageName "***"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        testHandleProfiling true
        testFunctionalTest true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
            runProguard false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        test {
            packageNameSuffix ".test"
            runProguard false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    jacoco {
        version = '0.6.2.201302030002'
    }

    testOptions {
        resultsDir = "$project.buildDir\\jacoco"

    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.activeandroid:activeandroid:3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile('org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.1'
}
```